# Kanji 行 with なみ, なめ, みち and アン pronunciations

Tags: kanji, pronunciation

I have only found 行 being pronounced as いく, ゆく and おこなう for kun'yomi and as コウ and ギョウ for on'yomi, but my dictionary software also lists down なみ, なめ, みち and アン as the other pronunciations of this kanji.

[image: Pronunciations of 行]

In which words is the kanji 行 pronounced as なみ, なめ, みち or アン?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Names, mostly. Hence most of them being [nanori](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanori) readings. But [a few as 「アン」](http://dic.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?ei=UTF-8&p=%E8%A1%8C%20%E3%81%82%E3%82%93&fr=dic&stype=prefix) as well.

- 行火 (あんか) - foot warmer
- 行脚 (あんぎゃ) - pilgrimage
- 行宮 (あんぐう) - temporary lodging built for an imperial visit
- 行灯 (あんどん) - a lamp with a paper shade

Comment: So 'nanori' means kanji readings that are used in names? I didn't realized the 'nanori' in the popup has such significance ..

Answer (score 5):

For the nanori reading(s):

- 行方 (**なめ**がた, **なめ**かた) : a place name in the Kanto area ← 行細（なめくわし＝並べ詳しき） ([source](http://inu.imagines.jp/yamato/hudoki.html))

Extra:

- 行縢 (**むか**ばき) : certain type of legwear used by samurais in the middle ages, still worn as part of formal attire for horseback archery
- 行幸 (**み**ゆき) : the Emperor's visit ← probably from a synonym: 御幸 (みゆき)

Comment: Just to note, 行方 = ゆくえ (someone's "whereabouts") as well, and is far more common.  Just don't want the OP (@Lukman) to get used to mentally reading it as the above 地名.

Answer (score 4):

As the others have already said, most of those are nanori readings. The アン reading, however, is what is called a Tō-on (唐音) reading. These are Chinese readings from a later period than the usual Go-on (呉音) and Kan-on (漢音) readings.

Answer (score 2):

Probably in family names for the kun.

For the on, there is 行脚 (angya), pilgrimage that I know.